# Deleting Google Contacts after a number of days if found with a specific label

Tags: label, google-contacts-api

I'll preface this by stating that I'm completely new to Google's Script Service and do not know how to create code from scratch, however I can interpret code at a novice degree...

I would like to automatically delete contacts with a specific label after a specific number of days.  The trigger would run every 24 hours.

I just don't know where to begin to start writing a function like this.  Is there anyone out there who can throw something together?  I currently have a script that deletes e-mails with a specific label, but not contacts.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll give you something to start with. You can go to [Class Contact](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#deleteContact()) which contains the [deleteContact](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#deleteContact()) method. You can also check the full [Contacts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/) reference to

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that we can address the "Label" field.  I can see how we can pull information from the contact data based upon the "label" of the data... i.e. (First Name / Last Name / Etc...) but the field that I would need to look at is the one that's actually called "Labels."  It doesn't seem to exist.  The data in the CSV is a single field delimited with multiple labels on each record, so it's a bit confusing.